# Stop page load for certain browser

Tags: asp.net

I'm running a asp.net mvc3 website. I want to check which version of IE is running, if the browser is not ie9 i need to stop the page and post an error message.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I have tried this

```
  var ie = (function(){

        var undef,
            v = 3,
            div = document.createElement('div'),
            all = div.getElementsByTagName('i');

        while (
            div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE ' + (++v) + ']><i></i><![endif]-->',
            all[0]
        );

        return v > 4 ? v : undef;

    }());

    if (ie < 9) {
        console.log('ie');
        document.write('<div class="page-error">' + 'bad' + '</div>');

        /*Must throw and not catch this exception in order for the page to stop loading further.*/
        throw "Invalid page exception";
    }
```

But it still renders the entire page and displays an error.. How can i stop page loading and display an error if no in the correct browser?

Answer (score 2):

Stopping the load of a page is not a normal behavior.  Your best bet is to do a redirect or logically branch your code( Assuming it's javascript ) so that it doesn't run on a particular browser.  Possibly hide/show a div based on browser support.

Even better than detecting a browser, detect the presense of certain features that you need.  Have a look at modernizr for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this entirely on the Server-side and simply redirect the user to an error page. Something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if(!Request.Headers["User-Agent"].Contains("MSIE 9.0"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
    }
}
```

If you don't want to do the `Response.Redirect`, then simply write to the Response directly as so:

```
Response.Write("<div> Error - go get IE9 </div>";
Response.End();
```

Note: no method will be infallible, server or client-side detection can always be tricked.

Comment: would this need to go in the application_start()?

Comment: @deep not at all. Application_Start won't do because it only happens once. You can do it on Session_Start and that's probably a better approach if you want to do this system-wide. Otherwise, putting it on page_load or on a custom base page from which all your pages derive from makes more sense.